# Styled Radio buttons won't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

why is my code not working properly? 
I want it to work like this:
https://www.16personalities.com/free-personality-test

Here ist my code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29845/

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 caption left" onclick="setAnswer(2, -3);">Agree</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons" aria-label="Options">
                            <fieldset id="group2">
                                <label class="btn agree max" onclick="setAnswer(2, -3);">
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn agree med" onclick="setAnswer(2, -2);">
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn agree min" onclick="setAnswer(2, -1);">
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn neutral" onclick="setAnswer(2, 0);">
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn disagree min" onclick="setAnswer(2, 1);">
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn disagree med" onclick="setAnswer(2, 2);">
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn disagree max" onclick="setAnswer(2, 3);">
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" autocomplete="off">
                                </label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 caption right" onclick="setAnswer(2, 3);">Disagree</div>
```

I don't have any JS on my site except the preinstalled Bootstrap scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[I forked your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jany_boi/rkarsas7/34/) to make the changes.

To target an input element, use the attribute selector. So for your case, you can target the radio button by doing this `input[type="radio"]{..insert css properties here..}`. Since you don't want to display the radio buttons, you set the opacity to 0. You also use z-index to make sure it's gone all the way behind, and can set the z-index to any value of your choice but lets behave ourselves over here and set it to -1. This should help hide the radio buttons.

```
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just set it to display none.

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}
```

Both of the above properties do a good job of hiding the radio buttons.

Moving on, instead of using the :active and :focus pseudo selectors, I've used the label classes that you have specified viz. agree, neutral and disagree to make the background change to the respective colors.

So, after you specify the css properties for the .btn class, you then use the pseudo class of hover and set the background color for mouse hover and then target the .active class to set the background color permanently to the specified color.

```
.btn.agree:hover, .btn.agree.active{
  color: #4C9070;
  background-color: #4C9070;
}
```

What this does is it uses the same color for hover and when you click on the option, i.e. the option is active. You can then define css for the neutral and disagree classes in the same way, by replacing .agree with .neutral and .disagree respectively.